# echo an <img> tag

Tags: php, string, image

I'm going crazy trying to echo an `<img>` tag.

I want to add this simple string `"/uploads/"` before `$photo->name`.

Here is my echo: `echo '<img src="'.$photo->name.'"/>';`

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not sure if I completely understand, but try this:

```
echo '<img src="/uploads/'.$photo->name.'"/>';
```

Comment: Just a word of caution. Please encode your output with htmlspecialchars.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:
`echo '<img src="/uploads/'.$photo->name.'"/>';`

Or:

`echo '<img src="' . '/uploads/' . $photo->name.'"/>';`

Or:

`echo '<img src="' . "/uploads/" . $photo->name.'"/>';`

Answer (score 1):

`echo '<img src="/uploads/'.$photo->name.'"/>';`

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
 echo '<img src="/uploads/'.$photo->name.'"/>';
```

... unless I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

two ways to use echo tag

1st : one is **double** quotes which use for out put of strings

```
echo "your name is".$name //here name is variable
```

2nd : one is **single** quotes in which you can use all html tags here is the example

```
  <?php

     $name="Adil";
     echo $name;
     for($i=0;$i<44;$i++)
     {
       echo($i.'<br>')     ;
       if($i==10)
       {
         echo ' <table border=3> <tr><td><h1>its image </h1><img src="examp.png" alt="loading" /><td><td>hello</td><tr></table>';

       }
     }
     ?>
```

here i am using multiple tags in echo using

> single quotes

if put double quotes then you will see following error
*Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Untitled2d.php on line 21*

here is the output
[image]